# What's the smartest way to find the scale of an unrestricted numeric type?

Tags: postgresql, decimal

By laziness and convenience I integrated quite a lot of data from a partner in an unrestricted *numeric* type in my PostgreSQL database.

However it now seems that depending of different shipments from this partner the scale of the *numeric* varies from zero to over 20 decimal places (or scale) which don't make a lot of sense and probably consume quite a lot of storage for no good reason. So I would like to restrict my *numeric* field to a reasonable scale.

However because my partner don't provide any recommendations I would like to identify the occurrence of each scale in my data-set to potentially identify a reasonable middle ground between 0 and 20 (zero obviously not being an option and given the 17 Million row-count, aggregated sums ARE going to be impacted by my decision).

It will also be needed during following rounding to avoid actually increase the scale of values that were shipped with a scale of zero.

---

Long story short, what the nicest way to compute that for a specific number stored as an arbitrary *numeric*?

Best I could come up to is that, but is there a more elegant way to do that without converting to text?

```sql
SELECT
  my_numeric,
  COALESCE(
    char_length(                            -- Finding size of string extracted by a...
      substring(my_numeric::text,'\.(\d*)') -- regexp to return all digits right from '.'
    ),                                      -- but if scale is 0 substring return NULL                               
  0                                         -- so I handled this inside a COALESCE
  ) AS my_numeric_scale
FROM
(VALUES
(0.1::numeric),
(0.12),(0.123),
(0.1234),
(0.12345),
(0.123456),
(0.000001),
(0.100000)
) foo (my_numeric)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *is there a more elegant way to do that*

Yes, use the [`scale()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) function which was introduced in 9.6:

```
SELECT my_numeric,
       scale(my_numeric)
FROM (
 VALUES
    (0.1::numeric),
    (0.12),(0.123),
    (0.1234),
    (0.12345),
    (0.123456),
    (0.000001),
    (0.100000)
) foo (my_numeric)
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MVJQR23795

Comment: At first I felt dumb because I promise I've parse this manual page quite a few time. Then I realize mistake... this function was apparently introduced in Postgresql 9.6 so I was fooled by my search engine and looked at an old version. Maybe you could edit your answer to point out this work for >9.6. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarHoff: that's another good reason to **not** use a search engine to find the manual, but jump to the manual of your Postgres version directly. Just bookmark http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html